# Retrieve data from two tables having id and display the max id of another table in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a two different tables

```
Table 1
id
name
description

Table 2
id 
details
info
table1_id
```

I want to display all the records from the `table1` except `id` but from `table2` I used to display the max `id`.

eg. `table1` have following records

```
id=1
name = test
description = some text

table2 have
id=5
details = some more text
info = the new info
table1_id = 1
```

so the result what I want is

```
id  name   description
5   test   some text
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
    (select max(table2.id) from table2 where table1.id = table2.table1_id) id,
    name,
    description
from table1
```

or `left join`:

```
select
    t.id,
    table1.name,
    table1.description
from table1
left join (
    select max(id) id, table1_id from table2 group by table1_id
) t on table1.id = t.table1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with and max.

```
with ID_Table_1_MaxID_Table_2 as (
  select table1_id, max(id) Max_Table2_ID
  from Table_2
  group by table1_id
)
SELECT tb2.id, tb1.name, tb1.description 
FROM Table_2 tb2
INNER JOIN ID_Table_1_MaxID_Table_2 sub 
ON (sub.table1_id = tb2.table1_id and tb2.id = sub.Max_Table2_ID)
INNER JOIN Table_1 tb1 on tb1.id = sub.table1_id
```